# How to copy specified file_name to specified_directory_name in ubuntu

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, command-line

I have some file, the name of files like

- CAB01_backup
- CAB02_backup
- CAB03_backup
- ...
- CAB120_backup

this files locate in directory name "files" (/home/files/)

and there are other directory besides "files" directory in the same path, the name of other directory like as name of file(CU-CAB01,CU-CAB02,..,CU-CAB120).

how can i copy/move the files to the same directory name with linux command or shell script ?

Comment: what have you tried? ... can you give a specific example of what you mean ie move `home/files/CAB01_backup` to where?

Comment: yes..i want to move the the file CAB01_BACKUP to CU-CAB01 directory..  mv /home/files/CAB01_backup /home/CU-CAB01/

Comment: this result command will i put to the crontab jobs, this command will be execute every day..because will be there the new files every day

Comment: if you want to make this a cron job right @Cairnarvon answer into a bash script and then add the script to your crontab to be run once a day

Comment: the direcotory where i will move the file already created..so the @Cairnarvon answered will be simplify: cd /home/files
for f in CAB*_backup; do  mv "$f" "CU_${f/_backup}"; done. thats true ?

Comment: yes that is true, you should also except his answer

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is the sort of thing you're looking for:

```
cd /home/files
for f in CAB*_backup; do mkdir "CU_${f/_backup}" && mv "$f" "CU_${f/_backup}"; done
```

The only part of that that may be confusing is the `${f/_backup}` syntax; that just replaces the string `"_backup"` in the variable `$f` with an empty string.

Comment: much nicer then my would be answer